# Print n characters using astreisk in nodejs

Tags: python, node.js

```
print "*" * 80
```

This is an elegant way to print delimiters (that has 80 astreisk symbols) in python log files. How can i do this in `nodejs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In node.js it is something like this:

```
console.log(new Array(80).join('*'));
```